# How to sort the dataset using clues in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large data set, but here is a set of my data:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"Cues   214 330 226
M   A   B   M
Z   Z   Z   Z
P   J   P   12
R   K   R   11

"
)
```

The Cues column guides me to get the following table. If it is the same letter, it will get 10, if not it will get a zero

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"214    330 226
0   0   10
10  10  10
0   10  0
0   10  0
"
)
```

Can we do it in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way in base:

```
df[] = lapply(df, as.character) # convert to character, if needed
result = df[-1]
result[] = lapply(result, function(x) ifelse(x == df$Cues, 10, 0))
result
#   X214 X330 X226
# 1    0    0   10
# 2   10   10   10
# 3    0   10    0
# 4    0   10    0
```

And `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) # across requires dplyr version 1.0 or higher
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(where(is.factor), as.character),  # convert to character, if needed
    across(-Cues, ~ if_else(. == Cues, 10, 0))
  ) %>%
  select(-Cues)
#   X214 X330 X226
# 1    0    0   10
# 2   10   10   10
# 3    0   10    0
# 4    0   10    0
```

Comment: Thank you I get Error in Ops.factor(x, df$Cues) : level sets of factors are differen

Comment: Could we do better?

Comment: Ah, your real data must be `factor` class, your sample data is `character` class. We can convert everything to `character` first. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

Using `across()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df2 <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.character(.))) %>%
  mutate(across(X214:X226,~ifelse(.==Cues,10,0))) %>% select(-Cues)
```

Output:

```
  X214 X330 X226
1    0    0   10
2   10   10   10
3    0   10    0
4    0   10    0
```

Comment: Thanks, I get Error in across(X214:X226, ~ifelse(. == Cues, 10, 0)) : 
  could not find function "across"

Comment: @user330 Try first loading `dplyr` with `library(dplyr)`

Comment: @user330 Also I have added an update for the factor issue! Hope that helps you!

Comment: Error in across(everything(), ~as.character(.)) : 
  could not find function "across" The devil is across

Comment: @user330 Try updating the package `dplyr` to the last version. Then you can try the code again. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: Thanks, can we do it using lapply?

Comment: @user330 Did you check the answer from Gregor? That uses `lapply()`.